# Can we solve this problem with analytic geometry and transfinite induction?

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-geometry

Can we solve this problem with analytic geometry and transfinite induction?
The solution must be with analytic geometry, not with euclidean geometry. 
Problem 4. Triangle ABC has circumcircle Ω and circumcenter O. A circle Γ with centre A intersects the segment BC at points D and E, such that B , D , E and C are all different and lie on line BC in this order. Let F and G be the points of intersection of Γ and Ω , such that A, F , B , C and G lie on Ω in this order. Let K be the second point of intersection of the circumcircle of the triangle BDF and AB segment. Let L be the second point of intersection of the circumcircle of triangle CGE and the segment CA. Suppose that the lines FK and GL are diferent and intersect at the point X. Prove that X is on the line AO .

Comment: Please do not change the question after receiving an answer . . .

Comment: Sorry, I need solve this problem urgently

Comment: @Julioqwert Why? What do you need to solve this problem for? Can you give *any* context?

Comment: I rolled back the edit by OP as it changes the question as to invalidate a big part of the answer already given.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I can provide the context that this is problem 4 from the 2015 IMO.

Comment: Is for the international mathematical Olympiad

Answer (score 3):

It's very difficult to prove that a technique cannot be useful for a given problem. That said, I'm going to go out on a limb here and say: "no, transfinite induction is not useful here."

Let me try to explain why. Transfinite induction is the following result:

> Suppose $\alpha$ is some ordinal, and $P$ is a statement such that $(i)$ $P(0)$ holds and $(ii)$ for every ordinal $\gamma<\alpha$, if $P(\beta)$ holds for all $\theta<\gamma$ then $P(\gamma)$ holds. (Note that $(i)$ is in fact redundant here.) Then $P(\gamma)$ holds for every ordinal $\gamma<\alpha$.

In particular, there are two things you want to look for in a problem to see that transfinite induction might be helpful:

- $(a)$ There is some way to view the "instances" of the problem as ordinals, and
- $(b)$ Under this viewpoint, instances with "smaller" ordinals are "simpler".

Now the axiom of choice seems to make point $(a)$ trivial: *every* set can be "ordinalized." So, for example, in the problem you mention the "instances" are configurations of points and circles in the plane; so why don't we just well-order that set and go from there?

Well, the answer is that this well-ordering is really ad hoc, and point $(b)$ won't be satisfied. Suppose I've shown that the statement holds for one instance of your problem; how do I show that it holds for the "next" instance? There is no obvious structure to the problem which lets you view one triangle as a "simpler" instance than another, let alone which does so in a way compatible with some well-ordering. So there is no "fingerhold" for transfinite induction to come into play.

Transfinite induction often seems magical at first glance, but it is a precise proof technique that requires specific hypotheses (just like standard induction!). Unless you see a reason for transfinite induction to work for a certain problem, you're unlikely to find it useful for that problem.

Comment: The answer is no?

Comment: @Julioqwert Well, as I said in my first sentence, it's very hard to show that a technique is not possibly useful in a given situation. However, there is absolutely no way I can see to use transfinite induction here, and there are serious obstacles to its use; and you have given no reason to believe that it *is* useful here. So, I would say, the answer is indeed **no**. (See the second sentence of my answer, where I basically say this.)

Comment: Can I solve this problem only with analytic geometry?

Comment: @Julioqwert Well, analytic geometry can prove everything Euclidean geometry can, so the answer is trivially yes. Whether it's useful is another matter (it may not simplify things, and indeed I don't see that it does here); similarly, whether it's allowed by the problem is another matter, since the problem might be posed *in the context of* Euclidean geometry.

Comment: I try with analytic geometry this problem, but the equations are very big big big big. I have equations of 4 pages.

Comment: @Julioqwert Why do you *want* to use analytic geometry with this problem? Just because you can in principle use a technique, doesn't mean you should . . .